# Не записываются данные в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал класс для логирования

```
class LogWrite(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.logfile = open(file, 'a')
        import datetime
        self.datetime = datetime.datetime
    def write(self, string, t=True):
        time = self.getTime() + ' | ' if t else ''
        self.logfile.writelines(time + string + '\r\n')
    def getTime(self):
        return self.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
    def __del__(self):
        self.logfile.close()
```

и он не работает, файл создается но ничего не записывается
переделал в такой вид:

```
class LogWrite(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.logfile = file
        import datetime
        self.datetime = datetime.datetime
    def write(self, string, t=True):
        time = self.getTime() + ' | ' if t else ''
        with open(self.logfile, 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(time + string + '\r\n')
    def getTime(self):
        return self.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
```

и все работает, но меня напрягает что каждый раз при записе открывается файл записываются данные и закрывается файл. Поэтому хотелось узнать почему код в первом варианте не работает?
Это мой первый код на python ранее имел дело только с php поэтому буду раз более развернутому объяснению.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, импорт модуля datetime нужно поместить в начало. Так полагается. Во-вторых, не записывается у вас потому, что после завершения метода __init__ ваш файл автоматически закрывается. Просто запись нужно осуществлять в одном методе с открытием.

Comment: Кстати, для логирования в питоне есть модуль logging. Пользуйтесь им, он очень удобный.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы все время не открывать-закрывать? Варианта два. Либо оформить все это вне класса в одной процедуре и тогда файл не будет закрываться. Или в методе write записывать не в файл, а в глобальную переменную, а при выходе из программы уже заносить данные в файл. Ну или все-таки пользоваться модулем logging.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, открыл файл вне класса и все работает. Сейчас посмотрю модуль logging

Answer (score 1):

Первый ваш код прекрасно работает. Просто запись в файл буферизуется. До тех пор, пока вы не закроете файл, буфер просто не сбрасывается на диск и вы не видите изменений файла. Чтобы закрыть файл вам нужно удалить ваш объект `LogWrite`:

```py
log = LogWrite('test.log')
log.write('test')
del log
```

Если же вы хотите видеть записи в лог до закрытия файла / удаления логера, то добавьте сброс буфера после каждой записи в файл:

```py
    def write(self, string, t=True):
        time = self.getTime() + ' | ' if t else ''
        self.logfile.writelines(time + string + '\r\n')
        self.logfile.flush() # <-- сброс буфера в файл
```